# how to redirect page to home once windows back button is pressed without login the user out?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this website designed and developed in code igniter, where user is booking ticket. once the ticket is booked, I am showing user the complete details on final page. Now what i want is, if user is pressing back button of windows, user should be redirected to home page where he started not on the actual previous page.

Comment: use custom button or link below or above the details with text as "go to home page". or create a home icon and wrap it with hyperlink of home page

Comment: i did that. but what if user pressed it.. it is going to very previous page. I want to prevent that.

Comment: see my solution for your problem it may help

Comment: Nothing is helping out here...

Comment: You can set a flashdata (http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#flashdata) in your session when showing the final page and in your previous page check if the flash data exists redirect to home page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom redirect from that page. if user explicitly calls that page.

When user will book ticket it will submit a form and with form you have `POST` data. pass an additional key with you post data in `hidden field` like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="booking_ticket" value="1">
```

Then when the user submits the form check for `booking_ticket` was available or not.

```
    if(empty($_POST["booking_ticket"]) && $_POST["booking_ticket"]==""){
        header("Location:home.php");
    }
```

`if  $_POST["booking_ticket"]==1` then this if will be bypassed and form will be submitted in hitting back button user will be redirected to home page.

Comment: it worked when form is submitted on previous page.. but when you go to previous page it is showing view of form but not submitting it, you have to click button to submit it..so above code won't apply on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below jquery for redirect your own url when clicking browser back button.put this code in your final detail page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

    $(window).on('popstate', function() {
      var hashLocation = location.hash;
      var hashSplit = hashLocation.split("#!/");
      var hashName = hashSplit[1];

      if (hashName !== '') {
        var hash = window.location.hash;
        if (hash === '') {
          alert('Back button was pressed.');
            window.location='www.example.com';
            return false;
        }
      }
    });

    window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');
  }

});
```

Comment: not working as it erases the entire parameter passed to url and replace with #forward.

Comment: have you put in your respective file

Comment: see it is not possible that current url passed variable same as new url.If you want do that then you have to pass new url in window.locaton

Comment: it's code igniter so there is one .ready function and i put it there but with the condition of page name.

Comment: are you using HTML 5 then try this one window.onpopstate = function(event)
{
    alert("location: " + document.location + ", state: " + JSON.stringify(event.state));
};